# detail text equivalent to tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, detailtextlabel

I'm wondering how to set a cell's detail text using an NSArray similar to

```
tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Example", @"Example2", nil];
```

I'm not sure if it's possible but surely this awesome community could find something :D

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need a string to set the text. So you need to create a string from your array. A quick scan of the docs for `NSArray` reveals a handy method named `componentsJoinedByString:`.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ ... ];
NSString *arrayText = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = arrayText;
```